# custom Dropdown control issue

Tags: acumatica

version: 5.20.1752

I have created one custom dropdown control on contact form CR302000,  the control looks good on screen, but the value of the control can't be saved (no error, but just nothing is saved), nor loading data from database.

I also have a custom textbox on that screen ,saving and loading the value of it both are working okay.

here is DAL code for dropdown:
    [PXStringList(new string[] {"1","2","3"}, new string[] {"EN","FR","BI"})]
    [PXDefault("1")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Language")]

What should I do to make custom dropdown to work?

Thanks

Comment: What's the rest of the definition for that DAC field.   off the top of my head, it sounds like you are using PXString not PXDBString.

Comment: I first did "add data field",  so usrCSLanguage data field is created, I can see the usrCSLanguage is created in contact data table in database as well. After publish the project, then I did "add control" to create dropdown, then went to DAC to modify the definition. The control is function fine on interface only, but not saving or loading to/from database.
I think I also tried to add [PXDBString(2)] into definition, but it did not help.

Comment: BTW, I would like to know how can I remove customize control from the system. I removed the dropdown control from interface, deleted DAC definition as well, publish the project, but I still can see the usrCSLanguage in the database table. is there a safe way to remove the column from database table??

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your column from the table manually using your preferred Db mgmt tool (eg. SQL Management Studio).  Or if the client is hosted, you can create a SQL script which drops the column from the table.  Then publish that SQL script.

Since you use version 5.20, consider building an extension table and DAC extension, for your user field.  You can find the details to create them in the Acumatica T300 course.

Jeff is correct.  You need to use the proper declarations - PXDBString, not PXString.  What is the name of your DAC that you work with?  Make sure it is not a PXProjection.